# How can I properly display Vietnamese characters in ColdFusion?

Tags: unicode, text, coldfusion

I having a hard trying to properly display Vietnamese text in ColdFusion. I've proper charset set to UTF-8 but still no luck. The same texts work fine in a HTML page. What else am I missing? Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

**Html:**
[image]

**ColdFusion:**
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things you need to watch out for, as far as I recall of the top of my head.

The first is to ensure that the .cfm file itself is saved as UTF-8 - this is a file system option, and will probably be settable in your editor. This ensures that the UTF-8 characters are correctly preserved when saving the file.

The other is that every .cfm file that includes any UTF-8 text should start with:

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8" />
```

This ensures that ColdFusion delivers the page to the browser in the correct format.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll try it tonight and post the results.

Comment: If you use CFBuilder 2 (beta), it'll have the UTF-8 BOM already by default and u don't even need <cfprocessingdirective>

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, when you display your working HTML, can you check the page encoding used by your browser (ie. in FireFox you can right-click+page Info). Maybe your text is not UTF-8 encoded that could explain the problem...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I,ll try it tonight and repsond back.